# What is the purpose of an Ethernet coupler that reverses all the pins?

Tags: networking, ethernet

As the photo shows, the pins are wired "straight across", rather than diagonally. This means that it does not work as an Ethernet/8P8C coupler because the transmit pins are [mapped to unused pins](http://www.ertyu.org/steven_nikkel/ethernetcables.html) (for 10/100 Mbit/s at least). Likewise, it doesn't act as a crossover either.

Is it wired wrong? Or is it a special form of a 1000Base-T crossover? Or is it perhaps used to correct the pins from another reversed device...?

[image: Coupler guts] [image: Coupler outer]

Comment: Maybe for a phone? Where did you find this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The color coding of the wires does not comply with computer wiring standards so it isn't CAT5 or CAT6 cabling.  The color code is for phone wiring - old style.

All the wires are completely crossed.  This is a coupler to connect to RJ-45 phone wires.  Probably was used to extend wire for a old office phone.

Comment: Well spotted. So this could be used, for example, for a point-to-point telephone link (assuming the phones had RJ45 cables)?

Comment: Assuming you mean to hookup the phones directly to each other?  No - much more involved in that - would require a telco simulator.  You need "battery" and dial tone and other support functions.  Also, this would be for an older phone system, probably, since newer systems do use CAT5/CAT6.